# Netbeans color scheme settings

Tags: sublime-text-2, color-theme

Trying to create Sublime Text environment in Netbeans editor.

The screen below is before moving cursor into any "path"

[image]

And after

[image]

As you see, bg color of multiple instances changed.

The problem is. How can I change this color? Can't find in settings. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tools > Options > Syntax tab > Language: PHP > Category: Mark Occurrence` and change background color from right hand dropdown list.